# Does divergence theorem demand that the boundary is of $C^1$ class?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find the official statement but Wikipedia article does not seem to state the regularity of boundary. Do we have to demand that $\partial \Omega\in C^1$? I can imagine that if we have a very weird curve, we might get in trouble, but I'm not sure $C^1$ is sufficient/necessary. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: The wikipedia article says "piecewise smooth boundary". What are you looking for?